# How many $n$-length sequences over $\{0, 1, 2\}$ are there that sum to a multiple of $3$

Tags: combinatorics

How many $n$-length sequences over $\{0, 1, 2\}$ are there that sum to a multiple of $3$

I don't even know where to start with it.

Comment: Hint: Whatever the first $n-1$ characters are, you can add another character to get one that meets your condition.

Comment: If you don't know where to start, then start by examining special cases with small $n$.  What is the answer for length-0 sequences? What is the answer for length-1 sequences? What is the answer for length-2 sequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of n-length sequence over $\{0, 1, 2\}$ is $3^n$. Third of them are divisible by 3, third gives remainder 1 and third gives remainder of 2.

Explain: For any sequence we can change the first term to obtain all numbers modulo 3 possible. This gives 1-1 function from sequences whose sum is divisible by 3, and the sequences that gives remainder of 1, so their size is equal.